# Outside table reference in trigger

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB as my database and I am running into some issues creating a trigger. The code is below:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_1` FOR EACH ROW 
     BEGIN
        IF NOT CONTAINS(`db`.`table_2`.`item`, NEW.item) THEN
            INSERT INTO `db`.`table_2` (`item`, `item_2`, `item_3`) VALUES (NEW.item, "foo", 
            "bar");
     END IF;
     END
```

The issue is that table_2 is in the database "db" along with table_1 but when this code is run, it gives me the error below:

```
SQL Error (1109): Unknown table 'table_2' in field list
```

I am very confused by this because it seems like I should be able to do this by everything I am reading. All I am trying to do is force an insert in one table to cause an insert into another table if the condition is not met.

Comment: I don't think MariaDB has a `CONTAINS()` function.  What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you intend:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_1` FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db.table_2 t2 WHERE CONTAINS(t2.item, NEW.item) THEN
        INSERT INTO `db`.`table_2` (`item`, `item_2`, `item_3`)
            VALUES (NEW.item, 'foo', 'bar');
     END IF;
 END;
```